# Calculating Percentage of land cover/land use images in ARCGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, image

[image: Image is classified by me for wildlife Division]
 I want to ask how each land use percentage can be calculated to show water, settlements, forest, agriculture percentages. Can you suggest the process?

Comment: There area tabulate area tool.

Answer (score 1):

You have this option using reclass and raster calculator. Reclass the raster file and inspect the attribute table.

Create a new **float** field in the attribute table > Right click on the field to open Field calculator. Multiply the field by 0.0009

This usually works for me and i have to cross validate the total area.